# Deno - Compile Error on TypeScript file (deno / rust)

Tags: typescript, rust, deno

I have the TypeScript below in a file called download.ts. It runs using
deno run --allow-all download.ts
but fails on
deno compile --allow-all download.ts

Is there something about the way imports are handled in Deno that is causing the issue? or some other code structure I need to write differently? I have gotten "hello world" examples to compile on my machine.

```
import { readerFromStreamReader, copy } from "https://deno.land/std/streams/conversion.ts";

async function download(url: string, path: string) {
    const rsp = await fetch(url);
    console.log(url);
    console.log(path);
    const rdr = rsp.body?.getReader();
    if (rdr) {
        const r = readerFromStreamReader(rdr);
        const f = await Deno.open(path, { create: true, write: true });
        // copy from reader to file
        await copy(r, f);
        f.close();
    }
}

const url = "https://qwerty224.s3.amazonaws.com/sample.zip";
const path = "C:/temp/sample.zip";

download(url, path);
```

There error I get during compile is:

Platform: windows x86_64
Version: 1.25.0
Args: ["C:\Users\mjlef\.deno\bin\deno.exe", "compile", "--allow-all", "download.ts"]

thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', C:\Users\runneradmin.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\eszip-0.25.0\src\v2.rs:512:60
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace

**UPDATE:**
If I change the import to

```
import { readerFromStreamReader, copy } 
     from "https://deno.land/std@0.149.0/streams/conversion.ts";
```

It works. Any more current version and it fails.
What is the long term solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state which version of Deno you're using, and at https://deno.land/std@0.153.0#releases it says this:

> Standard library is currently tagged independently of Deno version. This will change once the library is stabilized.
>
> To check compatibility of different version of standard library with Deno CLI see [this list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/dotland/main/versions.json).

What this means is that each version of the `std` library is only guaranteed to be compatible with a specific version of Deno, so if you're not compiling with the compatible versions of Deno and the `std` library modules you're importing, then compatibility is not guaranteed.

That said, no imports are necessary to pipe the [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) of a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) to the [`WritableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream) of an [opened file](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable@v1.25.0/%7E/Deno.open) in Deno:

Here's an example which you can reproduce that downloads the [Deno v1.25.0 zip archive for Windows](https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/tag/v1.25.0).

`./example.ts`:

```ts
// I create and use a temporary file path here,
// but you can specify your own path here instead:
const tmpFilePath = await Deno.makeTempFile();
console.log({ tmpFilePath });

const denoDownloadUrl =
  "https://github.com/denoland/deno/releases/download/v1.25.0/deno-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.zip";

const response = await fetch(denoDownloadUrl);

if (!response.body) {
  // Handle no response body
  throw new Error("Response has no body");
}

const file = await Deno.open(tmpFilePath, { write: true });
await response.body.pipeTo(file.writable);
// The file will be automatically closed when the stream closes

console.log("File written");
```

Running in the terminal:

```
% deno run --allow-write=$TMPDIR --allow-net=github.com,objects.githubusercontent.com example.ts
{ tmpFilePath: "/var/folders/hx/8E56Lz5x1_lswn_yfyt1tsg0200eg/T/5851c62f" }
File written

% file /var/folders/hx/8E56Lz5x1_lswn_yfyt1tsg0200eg/T/5851c62f
/var/folders/hx/8E56Lz5x1_lswn_yfyt1tsg0200eg/T/5851c62f: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yesterday, was my first day with Deno. Digging it... but have more learning to do for sure.